# Scope for acts_as_commentable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, scope, acts-as-commentable

Does anyone know of any scopes to check if a user has commented on a model? For example, something like this:

```
current_member.commented_on?
```

If there isn't, is there a way to create one?

Answer (score 0):

According to me. There are two possible ways to do it

1.First method

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.commented_on
    Your selection query like where("query what you want to do e.g current_member.posts")
    and you can also return values
  end
end
```

2.Second Method

```
second method
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :commented_on, -> { where("your query here") }
end
```